# Vector Bundles Categorically

Tags: general-topology, category-theory, vector-bundles

[Definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3k8A.png)

I understand the first two points of this definition. However I need assistance in understanding further the sentance:
It is required that the topology of $E_x$ as a subspace of $E$ coincides with its standard topology as a real vector space.

1. In abstraction the definition makes sense, but I would like to know what would the topology on $E_x$ look like as a vector space?
2. Since the pullback bundle is a bundle, is it possible that if we have a bundle $\pi_E: E \to X$ over a topological space $X$ and a map $f : X \to Y$ we can construct a bundle say $\pi_F:F \to Y$ over a topological space $Y$ ? Essentially my question is that is it possible to construct such a bundle using images ? what properties should the homomorphism $h: E \to F$ admit other than continuity?
3. Is there a sense of talking about a bundle being contained in another bundle?

For the third question, we can talk about topologies being contained in another, I want to understand if it is also possible for vector bundles.

The link for the paper: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/files/wirthmueller-vector-bundles-and-k-theory.pdf

Comment: Not topology on $E$: Topology on $E_x$.

Comment: Yes you are right.

Comment: Every finite dimensional real vector space has a canonical topology since it is isomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$ with the product topology.

Comment: For 3, read about subbundles. For 2: no, but one can talk about direct images (push forwards) of sheaves, which are very useful generalizations of bundles.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Is it true that locally $E$ looks like $X \times \mathbb{R}^n$ where $\mathbb{R}^n$ is the fiber?

Comment: Of course not. Did you make a typo?

Comment: I am trying to make sense of what you said but more precisely.

Comment: Well, what I wrote is correct, what you wrote is not, unless your $X$ means $\{x\}$. The product topology in my comment is the one of $n$ copies of the real numbers.

Comment: Oh I see I think it makes sence if it is $\{x\} \times \mathbb{R}^n$ where $\mathbb{R}^n$ is the fiber?

Comment: Yes, but you do not have to write $\{x\}$, it is excessive correctness, just like writing $1\cdot 5$ instead of $5$.

Comment: Alright Noted. For 2, I am considering a similar construction of a final and initial topology...so I wanted a similar notion in vector bundles.

Comment: OK, you do not always get what you want. The category of vector bundles was invented for its use in geometry and topology. It lacks some desirable categorical properties, just like the category of, say, smooth manifolds.

Comment: Is there a text or proof of why that it not possible?

Comment: I do not think so. Try it and see how this fails even when $f$ is a covering map.